# Disjoint union of keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes in two objects and produces a new object with a disjoint union of properties, such that the keys of properties that appear in both objects get the object index as suffix. Is there any way to correctly type the return type? I.e.:

```
export function disjointUnion<
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  U extends Record<string, any>
>(obj1: T, obj2: U) {
  const seenKeys = new Set<string>();
  const result = {} as Record<string, any>; // Want to type this

  for (const k of Object.keys(obj1)) {
    result[k] = obj1[k];
    seenKeys.add(k);
  }

  for (const k of Object.keys(obj2)) {
    if (!seenKeys.has(k)) {
      result[k] = obj2[k];
      continue;
    }

    result[k + 0] = result[k];
    result[k + 1] = obj2[k];
    delete result[k];
  }

  return result;
}

// v Any way to make make this typed as { job0: string; job1: string; age: number} ?
const obj3 = disjointUnion({ job: "developer", age: 30 }, { job: "teacher" }) ;
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgBv4W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I guess the other answer is similar enough to my approach so it's less likely that you'd want my answer.  In that case: I would be clear to note that your function doesn't guarantee a "disjoint" union of properties (at least no more than any object does) because you could do something like `disjointUnion({ job: "developer", age: 30 }, { job: "teacher", job0: 0, job1: 1 })` or `disjointUnion({ job: "developer", age: 30, job0: 0 }, { job: "teacher" })` and lose keys.  Might not be a big deal, but you should just be careful.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! Yeah, regarding applying the union it multiple times, I've thought about that, I have a simple way to solve that on the JavaScript side (instead of a function, I actually have the `disjointUnion` as a method on a class that stores a record of the keys that have been seen) but I thought solving that in TypeScript would just be a nightmare & more trouble than it's worth for my application. If you wanna take a crack at it, be my guest, I would definitely be curious to see a sane solution if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
type Merged<T extends Record<string, any>, U extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof U ? `${Extract<K, string>}0` : K]: T[K];
} & {
  [K in keyof U as K extends keyof T ? `${Extract<K, string>}1` : K]: U[K];
};
```

Here's a sample:

[image]

Taking a closer look,
`K in keyof T` returns all of the keys of object T, and remaps them as either `'${K}0'` (if that key exists in object U) or just `K` (if not). It then merges that with the keys of U, suffixed with `"1"`

Comment: that `Extract<K, string>` part is because TypeScript didn't like `${K}0` when K could be a `symbol`. tbh, I'm not sure how to handle that case!

Comment: "casts them" is not really a term you would use for [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  The `as` operator sometimes is referred to as "cast" (although the term "type assertion" is preferred), but the `as` in a mapped type key remapping clause isn't really doing the same thing, it's just reusing a keyword

Comment: TIL, thanks @jcalz